# how to show two widgets one after another within some time interval in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, future, flutter-widget

I am trying to show two widgets one after another within 2 seconds of time interval.

Here, First I am trying to show the text widget and after two seconds of time interval it should be change to dot widget.

I tried but I am unable to do this. I was stuck how to return the two widgets at a time one after another.

code:

```
 Widget _getNumberWidget(bool hasHighlight, Color color, String text) {
    final textStyle = context.appThemeData.passcodeFieldStyle.numberTextStyle.textStyle.copyWith(color: color);
    return Container(
      height: 35,
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: FittedBox(
        fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
        child: text.isEmpty ? _getDotWidget(hasHighlight, color, text) : _showChar(hasHighlight, color, text),
      ),
    );
  }

     Widget _showChar(bool hasHighlight, Color color, String text) {
        final textStyle = context.appThemeData.passcodeFieldStyle.numberTextStyle.textStyle.copyWith(color: color);
          AppText(
            text: text,
            style: context.appThemeData.passcodeFieldStyle.numberTextStyle.copyWith(textStyle: textStyle),
          );
        
        sleep(const Duration(seconds: 2));
        return _getDotWidget(hasHighlight, color, text);
      }
```

If I return the Apptext then the remaining two lines code will change to dead code. Can any one suggest me how to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use FutureBuilder like this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ShowWidgetWithInterval extends StatelessWidget {

  Future<bool> _setInterval() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
    return true;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _setInterval(),
      builder: (context, intervalSnapshot) {
        if (!intervalSnapshot.hasData) {
          return Text('Widget 1');
        }

        return Text('Widget 2');
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `state`, define variable:

```
bool _showDotWidget = false;
```

Instead of `sleep`, use `Future.delayed`

```
Widget _showChar(bool hasHighlight, Color color, String text) {
  if (_showDotWidget)
     return _getDotWidget(hasHighlight, color, text);
  else {
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:2), () {
      setState({
        _showDotWidget = true;
      });
    });
    final textStyle = context.appThemeData.passcodeFieldStyle.numberTextStyle.textStyle.copyWith(color: color);
      return AppText(
        text: text,
        style: context.appThemeData.passcodeFieldStyle.numberTextStyle.copyWith(textStyle: textStyle),
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: It is returning App Text and not showing dot widget

Comment: Please show build method code, where you call _showChar

Answer (score 0):

Check my simple implementation using `Future.delayed`, which fires setState after 5 seconds to set a value (isElapsed=true).

```
class _ShowWidgetsState extends State<ShowWidgets> {
  bool isElapsed = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    //Delay for 5 seconds before setting 
    //isElapsed to true
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
      print('Displaying');
      setState(() {
        isElapsed = true;
      });
    });

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Show Widgets'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text('First Widget'),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10.0),
          Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              //Use Visibility Widget to show
              child: Visibility(
                visible: isElapsed,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  child: Text('Second Widget'),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FutureBuilder` and customize `StatelessWidget` insead of a function:

```dart
FutureBuilder(
        future: Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3)),
        builder: (c, s) => s.connectionState == ConnectionState.done
            ?  Text("Dot widget with text: $text") 
            // Pass here SizedBox.shrink(); in case you do not want to render anithing
            : const Text("Dot widget is loading..."));
```

**Full code to reproduce:**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String? text;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      home: Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              text = 'Some text';
            });
          },
        ),
        body: Center(
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
                color: Colors.lightGreen, child: NumberWidget(text: text))),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NumberWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool hasHighlight;
  final Color color;
  final String? text;
  const NumberWidget(
      {Key? key,
      this.hasHighlight = false,
      this.color = Colors.lightGreen,
      this.text})
      : super(key: key);

  //Helper function for a text variable.
  bool isEmpty(String? s) => s == null || s.trim().isEmpty;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (isEmpty(text)) {
      return const Text("Text is empty");
    }
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3)),
        builder: (c, s) => s.connectionState == ConnectionState.done
            ?  Text("Dot widget with text: $text") 
            // Pass here SizedBox.shrink(); in casde you do not want to render anithing
            : const Text("Dot widget is loading..."));
  }
}
```

**Result:**

[image]